# Having a problem with referencing Farseer into my Monogame project

Tags: c#, physics, monogame

I am trying to load in the Farseer Physics Engine into my current Monogame project and whenever doing so, the Farseer solution will load in correctly but then when I try and reference it, it gives me an error:
[image: Farseer Error]

I cannot find any information or anyone else that had this issue so if anyone has any tips or solutions on how to include or reference this project then I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Does the DLL in question actually exist at the path in question? Is this error in Visual Studio's project browser, or is it a build-time error?

Comment: You see this is my problem, in my project the DLL isn't there, but in every tutorial that I have seen they do have a DLL, so I am assuming that I have an updated version or something?

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the latest version of mongame. Delete and reinstall the previous version. I think it is 3.4.